# Passing string to Angular expression from app.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got this function which redirects to the login page when certain conditions are met. This part is working fine, but I want a message on the login page saying why they were redirected.

Currently I have this function within my app.js

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
        //stuff to evaluate
        if (stuff = true) {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function () {
                $scope.message = "test";
                $window.location.assign('#/login');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And I also have a page, login.html, with a div where I want my message.

```
        <div ng-hide="message == ''" class="alert alert-danger">
            {{message}}
        </div>
```

I have tried adding $scope to the function, and accessing $scope.message, but I don't think I'm in the correct scope. The function never hits when I include this, but it does without. Is there any way I can access the scope of this login.html page? The login page does have it's own controller, but I need to be able to redirect to there from this app.js page.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're going to attach the message to `$scope`, why not attach it to `$rootScope`? It's a singleton which is always available. I'm not saying it's the best strategy, but it should work at least for testing. Then later you can create a separate service which can hold messages.

Comment: @FrankModica Thank you for the help, this worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope gets re instantiated (recreated) once you navigate to the new state login, instead of using $scope, you should user **`service/root$scope/localStorage`** to pass the value to the next page.

Change it using $rootScope as,

```
 $rootScope.$evalAsync(function () {
         $rootScope.message = "test";
         $window.location.assign('#/login');
 });
```